# JavaFX put RadioButtons into GridPane

Tags: javafx, radio-button, gridpane

I have the following piece of code:

```
GridPane gp = new GridPane();

// filling GridPane with other nodes...

RadioButton maschio = new RadioButton("M");
RadioButton femmina = new RadioButton("F");
final ToggleGroup tg = new ToggleGroup();
maschio.setToggleGroup(tg);
femmina.setToggleGroup(tg);
gp.add(tg, 1, 3);
```

I got an error on the last line saying: `ToggleGroup cannot be converted to Node`.

What can I do? I also tried with `Vbox, Hbox` but it didn't work.
Tried to Google but didn't find the solution. Any suggestions?

Comment: Added a possible solution

Answer (score 2):

```
    ToggleGroup tg = new ToggleGroup();
    RadioButton male = new RadioButton("Male");
    male.setToggleGroup(tg);
    RadioButton female = new RadioButton("Female");
    female.setToggleGroup(tg);
    HBox box = new HBox(20, male,female);
    gp.add(box,1,3);
```

Toggle a control that can be toggled between selected and non-selected states. In addition, a Toggle can be assigned a ToggleGroup, which manages all assigned Toggles such that only a single Toggle within the ToggleGroup may be selected at any one time.

Answer (score 0):

I found the following solution:

```
    ToggleButton maschio = new RadioButton("M");
    ToggleButton femmina = new RadioButton("F");
    final ToggleGroup tg = new ToggleGroup();
    HBox rbContainer = new HBox(maschio, femmina);
    maschio.setToggleGroup(tg);
    femmina.setToggleGroup(tg);
    gp.add(rbContainer, 1, 3);
```

Is it ok? or you have better solutions?

Comment: Ref ToggleButton http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15819242/how-to-make-a-button-appear-to-have-been-clicked-or-selected-javafx2