# style pressed button in JavaFX

Tags: java, css, javafx

I've got a `Button` in my `FXML` file and i give a style to it by below `CSS`

```
.button {
    -fx-background-color: linear-gradient(#ff5400, #be1d00);
    -fx-background-radius: 30;
    -fx-background-insets: 0;
    -fx-text-fill: white;
}
```

[image]

as you can see the button has a new awesome style, but whenever i click on it, it remains as like as before and you can't understand is it clicked or not...

As I searched, I found one solution in this link: [Pressed  CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15463854/pressed-button-css), but if you notice it is The CSS that is used by Web Browsers and JavaFX does not support it.

so what is the solution? I want my button changes its appearance when the users hit or click it.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You need to add the psuedoclass state `pressed` to you css and add new css to it, which will differentiate your current button css with that when pressed :

```
.button:pressed {
    // Your new css
}
```

For changing the style while `hovering the button` use :

```
.button:hover { 
    // Your new css
}
```

For better understanding of what style you can add for styling the button, you can go through [How to make a button appear to have been clicked or selected?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15822117/1759128)

Comment: Thank you it is true, but have you ever notice that when you put the mouse on the button ( before clicking) the appearance of button changes, an then whenever click it, again it changes. can you understand what i am trying to say?

Comment: For that you need to use the pseudoclass `hover`, i.e. `.button:hover { ... }`.  The [CSS Reference Guide](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html) lists pseudoclasses and properties for all components, such as [`Button`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html#button)

Answer (score 1):

for arrayLists on javaFX, try this on the CSS to change colors on mouse click:

.list-cell:selected { -fx-background-color: yellow; }